# Component doesn't open in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

There are two ways to open my component, one from navigation bar and other is to open the same component in dialog box. There is only a submission form inside the component.

I want the dialog to be automatically get closed when user submits the form. All the good till here. the real problems occurs now, If the use following statement to close the dialog
`ts` file

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewCustomerComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public display: any

  ){...}
```

closing statement after form-submission
`this.dialogRef.close();`

The dialog gets closed successfully, but the same component stops working from navigation link, works without any problem if I open it using dialog box, but never opens I click the navigation link and the following error occurs.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NewCustomerComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NewCustomerComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NewCustomerComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NewCustomerComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:778)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:27491)
    at resolveDep (core.js:28021)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

and this is how I'm invoking my dialog

```
openCustomerDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewCustomerComponent, {
      width: '700px',
      height: '600px',
      data: {
        view: 'dialog'
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('OpenCustomer Dialog was closed');
      this.getCustomers()
    });
  }
```

I already tried to include the Material libraries in `app.module.ts` and `component` file. and tried the following too
`providers: [{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }]` in component's module file

If I remove the
`public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewCustomerComponent>` statement. component opens fine from both ways, but the dialog doesn't get closed.

Upon request, here is my `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
// import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatDialogModule, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import 'hammerjs';

import { FuseModule } from '@fuse/fuse.module';
import { FuseSharedModule } from '@fuse/shared.module';
import { FuseProgressBarModule, FuseSidebarModule, FuseThemeOptionsModule } from '@fuse/components';

import { fuseConfig } from 'app/fuse-config';

import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';
import { SampleModule } from 'app/main/sample/sample.module';
import { AddSalesPersonComponent } from './layout/components/Sales/add-sales-person/add-sales-person.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './layout/components/login/login.component';
import { MasterLayoutComponent } from './master-layout/master-layout.component';
import { NewLoanComponent } from './layout/components/loan/new-loan/new-loan.component';
import { ListSalesComponent } from './layout/components/Sales/list-sales/list-sales.component';
import { NewCustomerComponent } from './layout/components/customer/new-customer/new-customer.component';
import { CustomerListComponent } from './layout/components/customer/customer-list/customer-list.component';
import { NewOrganizationComponent } from './layout/components/organization/new-organization/new-organization.component';
import { ListOrganizationComponent } from './layout/components/organization/list-organization/list-organization.component';
import { NewProductComponent } from './layout/components/products/new-product/new-product.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './layout/components/products/product-list/product-list.component';
import { NewAdminComponent } from './layout/components/admin/new-admin/new-admin.component';
import { ListAdminComponent } from './layout/components/admin/list-admin/list-admin.component';
import { LoanListComponent } from './layout/components/loan/loan-list/loan-list.component';
import { ReceivePaymentComponent } from './layout/components/payments/receive-payment/receive-payment.component';
import { MakePaymentComponent } from './layout/components/payments/make-payment/make-payment.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MasterLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/login',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'saveSalesPerson',
                component: AddSalesPersonComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'searchsalesperson',
                component: ListSalesComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'newcustomer',
                component: NewCustomerComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'searchcustomer',
                component: CustomerListComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'neworganization',
                component: NewOrganizationComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'searchorganization',
                component: ListOrganizationComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'newproduct',
                component: NewProductComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'searchpoduct',
                component: ProductListComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'newloan',
                component: NewLoanComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'searchLoan',
                component: LoanListComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'newadmin',
                component: NewAdminComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'searchadmin',
                component: ListAdminComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'receivePayments',
                component: ReceivePaymentComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'makePayments',
                component: MakePaymentComponent
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
    },

    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'salesperson'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),

        TranslateModule.forRoot(),

        // Material moment date module
        MatMomentDateModule,

        // Material
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,

        // Fuse modules
        FuseModule.forRoot(fuseConfig),
        FuseProgressBarModule,
        FuseSharedModule,
        FuseSidebarModule,
        FuseThemeOptionsModule,

        // App modules
        LayoutModule,
        SampleModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MasterLayoutComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatRippleModule,

    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }]
    
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, but can you please let me know what does that navigation mean? or can you provide stackblitz link?

Comment: Did you add `MatDialogModule` to your module? show us your module file

Comment: stackblitz would be a problem, because my application uses many different libraries, 
navigation means a simple regular navigation link

Comment: @benshabatnoam yes obviously

Comment: Show us the code. As per the error I think there is something wrong in the providers array in the module

Comment: Do you have your component in some other html component?

Comment: yes @benshabatnoam component is in another html file

Comment: @SelakaN I already provided my code

Comment: Can you show me the app.module.ts You mat dialog opening and closing doesnt seems to be having anthing wrong

Comment: @SelakaN yes I just edited the question, please take a look now

Comment: Check Try adding the MatDialogModule in app module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of those helping hands.
Although none of the above solution worked, but you guys motivated me alot to try different other solutions and the solution that worked for me was to add

`providers: [{ provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }]`

in my `app.module.ts` file

Answer (score 1):

`MatDialogModule` Module isnt there in you imports array in `app.module.ts` Try importing `MatDialog` and `MatDialogModule` in you app.module.ts

.

Comment: I just imported it and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Updated the answer. Try adding all three of them

Comment: I tried and now the `Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'MatDialogRef' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation` error is showing. I
updated my `app.module.ts` file in question, please have a look

Comment: I'm sorry just remove `MatDialogRef` from the module.ts only and see. That will do.

Comment: did the same, application runs, but my problem is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204836/discussion-between-selakan-and-lint).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `MatDialogModule` to `imports` in your module declaration:

```
import {MatDialogModule, MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    MatDialogModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  entryComponents: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

**Edit:** 
In your `app.module.ts` file could you replace this line:

```
import {MatDialogModule, MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

by this one:(correct import)

```
import {MatDialogModule, MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
```

Comment: I already imported it, but it is still giving me the same error

Comment: try to import it from  '@angular/material' not '@angular/material/dialog'

Comment: @Lint did you try it ?

Comment: I did, and updated the `module` file in my question too, please have a look

Comment: I checked your updated `app.module.ts` file you are importing your dependencies from `'@angular/material/dialog'` please check the edit section in my  answer

Comment: @ic_paty Importing the `dialog` entry point should be the preferred way for importing the dialog-related components/modules from Angular Material v9 and up as the team will be removing support for importing components/modules from the root entry point from v9 onwards.